# fwupdate running constantly with 200% CPU usage

Tags: 16.04, power-management, battery, cpu, cpu-load

I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop, and now it is constantly at 200 % CPU, and it gets quite hot.

[Here is what it looks like when I run top in the terminal. I have also included my drivers and my computer specifications.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFWjH.jpg)

I have also had issues with the battery draining unusually fast, because of this I assume. I was using Windows 10 before and there I was getting much more battery time. I'm using laptop-mode-tools, powertop, and have tuned the options using powertop --autotune, since I've heard that it could be useful. I also tried TLP, to no avail. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

From your top screenshot seems like `fwupdate` command is having issues.
Try to remove it from your system with `sudo apt remove fwupdate --purge`

Note: as for the title of your question: there IS an app running with 200% CPU - fwupdate.

Comment: That's a bit drastic. The application is likely misconfigured or in a bad state and will remain so when OP reinstalls it to actually use it to perform a firmware upgrade. -1

Comment: I have to kill the fwupd process every time I reboot for the issue to go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it running all the time, you could limit it's cpu useage with a program like [`cpulimit`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cpulimit&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

It picks a target based on a PID, an executable filename, or the absolute path of the executable. You'd probably want to use the absolute path:

```
cpulimit --path=/usr/bin/fwupdate --limit 10 &
```

Or here's an example using `pgrep` to find a PID:

```
cpulimit -p $(pgrep fwupdate) --limit 10 &
```

It should be able to kill instead of just "limit" too, with `--kill`, I'm not sure if it still needs a `--limit` set to know when to kill...

Or you could occasionally / regularly run `pkill fwupdate` to kill it whenever it's running.

---

The program does sound like it's getting stuck in some sort of "check for updates" loop, so likely a bug. I doubt you'd want to check for firmware updates very often, so if I weren't using the program I'd probably just remove / purge it too (if it's not vital to lots of other packages), it's only about 200k, then re-install it temporarily to check for updates. There are ways to stop it from running at boot too, I *think* it might be a systemd service (or at least the .deb has a fwupdate-cleanup.service file in /lib/systemd/system).

Comment: There is a bug report for it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream-glib/+bug/1591868
And it is said to be fixed in the latest version. Problem is updating it with `fwupdmgr update` doesn't work, "No devices can be updated: nothing to do".

Comment: But I guess I can settle with killing the process manually :/